# Cannot launch Google App Engine on Windows 7

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Every time I try to run the GAE Launch, an error occurs and is save in GoogleAppEngineLauncher.exe.log.

I opened it, and found the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "GoogleAppEngineLauncher.py", line 42, in <module>
 File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7913, in __init__
 File "wx\_core.pyc", line 7487, in _BootstrapApp
 File "launcher\app.pyc", line 53, in OnInit
 File "launcher\app.pyc", line 98, in _CreateModels
 File "launcher\preferences.pyc", line 62, in __init__
 File "launcher\platform.pyc", line 435, in PythonCommand
IndexError: list index out of range
```

What's the problem here?

I am using Python 2.7.6 (64bit).
And the GAP SDK is Windows 1.8.8 - 2013-11-19

Comment: What version of the AppEngine SDK, what version of Python on your machine?

Answer (score 1):

I uninstalled the 64 bit version Python and installed 32 bit, and then AppEngine works!

Comment: This works for me. Windows 7 Ultimate SP1, Python 2.7 (installed for all users), GAE v1.8.1, thanks !!! (64bit spoils GAE)

Answer (score 0):

As per the link below, the problem is that you have to have a windows-based Python installation...use an installation that came from an MSI file.

A cygwinny or ortherwise non-windows installation (i.e. just unzipping a python.zip file) will NOT work with Google App Engine.

Gee, thanks Google for making such quality software.

Here's yer link:
https://code.google.com/p/google-appengine-wx-launcher/source/browse/trunk/launcher/platform.py?r=5